# Android 13: How to check PackageManager.getPackageInfo(String, PackageInfoFlags) in JNI C?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-13

PackageManager.getPackageInfo(String, Int) is deprecated starting from Android 13 (SDK 33).

The documentation says to use `PackageManager.getPackageInfo(String, PackageInfoFlags)` instead.

So I tried to access the method in JNI with the following code but it gives me:

`NameNotFoundException`.

I am new to JNI so I have no idea what is wrong with this. How can I retrieve packageInfo with PackageInfoFlags in JNI? Here is my code snippet.

```
jmethodID getPackageInfo = env->GetMethodID(packageManagerClass, "getPackageInfo",
                                                "(Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager$PackageInfoFlags;)Landroid/content/pm/PackageInfo;");
```

Comment: The `NameNotFoundException` is something that `getPackageInfo` is allowed to throw. I do not think this is a JNI issue.

Comment: Yes I know this is not a JNI issue but the problem is I don’t know what is causing this exception to be thrown. There must be something wrong with how I get packageInfo with PackageInfoFlags because it all works fine for PackageManager.getPackageInfo(String, Int) with this code.
                                                ```(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/content/pm/PackageInfo;”);```

Comment: There might be an issue with the values you're passing, but you only shared your `GetMethodID` call so we have no way of knowing. How do you construct the `PackageInfoFlags` argument, for example?

Comment: I passed the PackageInfoFlags value like this ```getPackageInfo(pkgName, PackageManager.PackageInfoFlags.of(PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES.toLong())```

Comment: Does this exact invocation work in plain Java? Again, I really do not think this is a JNI issue unless the translation to PackageInfoFlags was messed up somewhere.